# curves on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove the following result.
Let $X\in \mathcal{T{(M)}}$ a vectorial field on a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and $\sigma$ a maximal integral curve of $X$.
i) Prove that if $\sigma$ is not constant then is injective or periodic. ii) prove that if $\sigma$ is periodic non constant then there exist a unique positive number $T_{0}$, the period of $\sigma$ iff $t-t'=kT_{0}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proof**

Before starting, it is useful to recall the definition of periodic curve

**Def** A curve $\sigma : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ in a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ is said periodic if there exist a a $T>0$ such that $\sigma(t)=\sigma(t+T)$ for every $t\in \mathbb{R}$

Let $\sigma:I\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ a curve in $\mathcal{M}$, where $I$ is the set of times where $\sigma$ takes value. Saying that $\sigma$ is not constant is like saying that there exists (at least), a time interval $T\subset I$ such that $\sigma(t_{0}+T)\neq \sigma(t_{0})$, where $t_{0}$ is the initial time of the curve $\sigma$. Considering the subset of $T$, $T_{1}$, it is not guaranteed that  $\sigma(t_{0}+T_{1})\neq \sigma(t_{0})$. If $\sigma(t_{0}+T_{1})= \sigma(t_{0})$ and $T_{1}$ is the smallest time interval in $I$ for which the condition above occurs; then $T_{1}$ is the period of $\sigma$ and hence $\sigma$ periodic. If this does not occur, we have that for every $T_{1}$ in $I$, $\sigma(t_{0}+T_{1})=\sigma(t_{1})\neq\sigma(t_{0})$, but this is equivalent to say $t_{0}\neq t_{1}\Rightarrow \sigma(t_{0})\neq\sigma(t_{1})$ which is the definition of injective curve.

ii) Assume that $\sigma$ is periodic non constant and that we have a unique $T_{0}$ such that $\sigma(t)=\sigma(t')$. By definition of periodic curve, $t'=t+T_{0}$ and $\sigma(t)=\sigma(t+T_{0})$ and this equality holds also if we add $T_{0}$ for an arbitrary number of times, let's say $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Moreover, if we make the change of variable $t'-T_{0}=t$ and subtract $T_{0}$ $\hspace{2mm}$ $k$ times, the equality continues to hold and hence $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence we have that $t-t'= kT_{0}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, let we assume by contradiction that $T_{0}$ is not unique (we already know that exists). We have $\sigma(t)=\sigma(t+T_{0})=\sigma(t+T^{*})= \sigma(t')$, with $T^{*}\neq T_{0}$. But $t-t'=kT_{0}$ and hence $kT_{0}=T^{*}$, hence $T_{0}$ is unique.

Let me know if it is correct.
I have a question about the sentence ii) Is it correct to say that on one hand, it assumes that $\sigma$ periodic and $T_{0}$ unique imply $t-t'=kT_{0}$; on the other, it say $\sigma$ periodic and $t-t'=kT_{0}$ imply $T_{0}$ unique ? In my proof, this interpretation is assumed as true by saying that $T_{0}$ is the period of $\sigma$ and so $\sigma$ is periodic; otherwise the concept of period would lose its meaning.

Thank you again for your time.

Comment: For the purposes of this proof, there's no need to find "the" period of a curve. A curve $\sigma$ is periodic if there exists *a* $T>0$ such that $\sigma(t+T)=\sigma(T)$. There are other choices of $T$, but any will suffice to show a curve is periodic.

Comment: You mean when I considered $T_{1}$ as the smallest time interval: a simple $T$ able to meet the condition $\sigma(t+T)=\sigma(t)$ would have been equally ok. However, are there any others imprecisions/errors? Is the proof correct? (However, the choice of $T_{1}$ does not sounds to me like an error, but rather like something unnecessarily restricting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your proposed proof. I will focus on point $(i)$, with a little effort I imagine this will give you hints on how to prove the second part.

First, notice that in the course of your argument you are not really using the assumption that $\sigma$ is an integral curve for a vector field $X$. If your argument was correct, it would show that *any* curve is either injective o periodic, which is absurd.

So, where does the relation between $X$ and $\sigma$ come into play? Let us recall the definition of integral curves: fix a vector field $X$ on $M$ and an interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. A smooth function $\sigma:I\to M$ is an integral curve for $X$ if at each point $p\in\sigma(I)$, $p=\sigma(t_0)$ one has
\begin{equation*}
\partial_t\Bigr|_{t=t_0}\sigma(t)=X_p.
\end{equation*}
This condition can be rephrased as the ODE
\begin{equation*}
\sigma'(t)=X_{\sigma(t)}.
\end{equation*}
In the proof of our Proposition, we should make use of this condition. A possible way to do so is to use the Picard-Lindelöf Theorem, a fundamental result for existence and uniqueness of solutions to ODEs. I will now sketch a proof of point $(i)$ in your question.

Assume that $\sigma$ is not a constant, and assume also that it is not injective. This means that there are two times $t_0,t_1\in I$ such that $\sigma(t_0)=\sigma(t_1)$, and let $T=t_1-t_0$. Let $\gamma(t):=\sigma(t+T)$; we will show that $\sigma(t)=\gamma(t)$ for all $t\in I$, which implies the periodicity of $\sigma$.

Let $p_0:=\sigma(t_0)$. The first curve, $\sigma(t)$, solves the ODE
\begin{equation}\label{sistema}
\tag{$1$}
\begin{cases}
\sigma(t_0)=p_0&\mbox{ (by definition of }p_0\mbox{)}\\
\sigma'(t)=X_{\sigma(t)}&\mbox{ (as }\sigma\mbox{ is an integral curve for }X\mbox{)}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
The first condition in \eqref{sistema} is also satisfied by $\gamma(t)$, as we are assuming $\sigma(t_0+T)=\sigma(t_0)$:
\begin{equation*}
\gamma(t_0)=\sigma(t_0+T)=\sigma(t_0)=p_0.
\end{equation*}
It is also easy to check that $\gamma'(t)=X_{\gamma(t)}$; I will leave this to you as an exercise. This shows that both $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ solve the initial value problem \eqref{sistema}. The Picard-Lindelöf Theorem then implies that $\sigma$ and $\gamma$ coincide, at least in a neighbourhood of $t_0$: there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for all $t\in[t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon]$,
\begin{equation}\label{periodic}
\tag{$2$}
\sigma(t)=\gamma(t)=\sigma(t+T).
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{periodic} is *almost* what we need to prove periodicity  of $\sigma$; can you go from here and finish the proof?